# How to align 3 columns that span 4 in 16 columns grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout with 16 columns. And for news i need to have 3 columns, each of them span on 4 columns of the grid container. How can i align those 3 columns with space evenly? - like on design

[image]

Because in this case justify-content doesnt seem to work as we have 16 columns. Please help me how to do this layout

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/oleksiukmary/pen/BqGQdg

```
@supports ( grid-area: auto ) {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
      grid-column-gap: 16px;
      justify-content: space-evenly;    
    }
```

Comment: Simply...don't use CSS-Grid if you're not going to align to it. Flexbox is the correct method here.

Comment: @Paulie_D but if you need a column to span on 4 grid columns? because grid is flexible and its a requirement :(

Comment: `justify-content: space-evenly;`  does not apply to CSS-Grid and `grid-gap` goes not create starting and ending gutters. So, at best, you might be able to add side padding...but that's a hack.